# How to fix the error caused by" when used with numbers and tapply? R, package arrangements

Tags: r, tapply

I'm using the package arrangements v1.1.5 with R v3.5.3 in Windows 10.
And I think I have found a strange error or I'm doing something wrong.

This is working

```
library(arrangements)
myDF <- data.frame(A=c("a","b","c"), B=c(2000,2000,2002))
tapply(myDF$A,myDF$B, permutations)

$`2000`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] a    b   
[2,] b    a   
Levels: a b c

$`2002`
     [,1]
[1,] c   
Levels: a b c
```

But this isn't working:

```
library(arrangements)
myDF <- data.frame(A=c(200,200,200), B=c(0,0,2))
tapply(myDF$A,myDF$B, permutations)

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : too many results
```

What am I doing wrong?
I just want to generate the permutations of the elements of A defined by the group B.
The result should be like the former example but with numbers instead of letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the documentation at `?permutations`. Note that the first parameter is described as

> x -- an integer or a vector, will be treated as `n` if integer; otherwise, will be treated as `v`

So the function behaves differently if you pass in a number or a factor. If you want to those values to be drawn from like the first example, you can just pass the value directly to the `v=` parameter.

```
tapply(myDF$A, myDF$B, function(x) permutations(v=x))
```